# How can I make sure route53 route traffic to two targets evenly?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, amazon-route53

I deployed two A records in host zone in route53.

- One A record is an alias to AWS hosted application load balance which is located in Sydney region.
- The other record is an A record points to an IP address hosted by load balance from GCP in Melbourne region.

And I am using `Weighted` routing policy that each has 200 weight. When I send requests from a laptop in Melbourne, all the traffic is routed to GCP load balance. It only route traffics to AWS when I bring down the application in GCP.

My question is how I can make sure route53 route traffic roughly evenly (not exact even) cross the two targets. Why does route53 route all traffic to GCP (Melbourne region)?

Comment: DNS resolvers cache DNS responses. That means if you test with the same machine, the same cached IP address is used. Test with multiple systems. Note: you can set the A record TTL to a small value (time).

Comment: I am using A record. How can I update its TTL?

Comment: it seems TTL doesn't work for alias?

Comment: Correct - alias records have a short predefined TTL. However, caching still has a major impact. Are the configuration details in your question?

Comment: I have listed two records, `A` and `A + alias`, using weighted policy. what kind of configuration you need? I'd like to achieve `no caching` on route53. I dont' care about latency or any side effect for now.

Comment: You cannot achieve `no caching` because you have no control over the client DNS resolvers. A resolver can choose to honor or ignore your TTL settings. Many will ignore short TTL values an others have bugs with caching. You have a fundamental misunderstanding of how DNS works in the real world. Use a load balancer instead of "poor man's DNS load balancing".

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. When you say `cached IP address`, does the ip address mean DNS resolved IP address or the client's IP address?

Comment: Cached IP address means that the IP address value for your DNS resource record cached at the client.

Comment: `cached at the client`? it means clients send the request to the target IP bypassing DNS?

Comment: The client first resolves a domain name to an IP address and remembers that response. Clients do not bypass DNS as DNS is not required for network communication, only for address lookup and translation.  Standard TCP/IP uses IP addresses to connect to other systems, not DNS.

Comment: that makes a lot sense, thanks.

Comment: In terms of `curl` command, is there a way to drop cache to make DNS resolve the domain name on every request?

Comment: Curl has no control over the IP address that DNS returns. Most systems have a command to flush the DNS cache. However, DNS is a globally distributed system. You can flush the local cache, but not the upstream DNS cache. My advice: stop trying to do load balancing with DNS - use a load balancer.

Comment: Load balancer is not global service. If a region is down, the whole application will go down?

Comment: If you have new questions, please post a new question. I have tried my best to explain why you should not use DNS to load balance.

Comment: Yes, created another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74806062/what-should-i-use-as-entry-point-for-multiple-cloud-application appreciate if you can have a look.